# Is there a better way to toggle between two buttons?

Tags: jquery

View it on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mm79v/

**My JQuery**

```
$(".SupOrSubButton").click(function(e) {
    var child = $(this).children().attr('id');
    if (child == 'Superscript') {
        if ($(this).hasClass('ButtonActive')) {
            $(this).removeClass('ButtonActive');
        } else {
            $('#Subscript').parent().removeClass('ButtonActive');
            $(this).toggleClass('ButtonActive');
        }
    } else if (child == 'Subscript') {
        if ($(this).hasClass('ButtonActive')) {
            $(this).removeClass('ButtonActive');
        } else {
            $('#Superscript').parent().removeClass('ButtonActive');
            $(this).toggleClass('ButtonActive');
        }
    };
});
```

I would love to know if there is a better way to do what I have done above using JQuery as I need to implement something similar elsewhere at a future date. I'm still learning JQuery and I know this works, however is it the best way, or even a good way?

Best Regards

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, but you could try this if you want to make it shorter:

```
$(".SupOrSubButton").click(function(e) {
    var child = $(this).children().attr('id');
    $(this).toggleClass('ButtonActive');
    $(".SupOrSubButton:not(:has(#" + child +"))").removeClass('ButtonActive');
});
```

Basically as your code, it adds the `ButtonActive` class if it's not there, and removes it if it is. And also removes `ButtonActive` from the non-clicked `.SupOrSubButton` div...

Edit:

To elaborate a little on:

```
$(".SupOrSubButton:not(:has(#" + child +"))").removeClass('ButtonActive');`
```

This piece of code has 3 parts, the first one selects the element(s) matching the `.SupOrSubButton` class, & the second one (`:not()`) negates the 3rd one (`:has()`) which looks for elements matching your `child` id inside the original selector.

Basically the selector as a whole means something like "look for elements with certain class which don't have a specific id as children"

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/3bVJ6/

Comment: Thank you, this seems a lot shorter and does exactly the same job! The only thing I am not sure whether I understand or not is "$(".SupOrSubButton:not(:has(#" + child +"))").removeClass('ButtonActive');" I understand what it does but not how it picks out the other one?

Answer (score 0):

Does this accomplish what you're trying to do?

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rdown/Ejcca/13/)

```
$(".group-1 .SupOrSubButton div").click(function (e) {
$(".group-1 div").removeClass('ButtonActive');
$(this).parent().addClass('ButtonActive');
```

});